# App catalog is not showing in site collection of SharePoint Admin Center

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, event-receiver, sharepoint-addin

I am working on SharePoint add-ins to create a remote event receiver. I have generated .app file and need to deploy on my SharePoint site. I followed the following reference to create app catalog for my site.

**Reference:** [Create App Catalog In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-app-catalog-in-sharepoint-online/)

After following all the above steps, I visited to site collections of the SharePoint Admin Center to get app catalog home lisk but app catalog is not showing there.
What did I do wrong while following the reference steps?

Answer (score 0):

Creating app catalog site collection in admin center does not always mean app catalog will be enabled for all sites (maybe it has been disabled).

Kindly use the below PowerShell script to enable app catalog for a particular site:

```bsh
$site = Get-SPOSite <Site collection url> 
Add-SPOSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site $site
```